# Document upload/sync with iTunes 11

Tags: itunes, ipad, windows

I have updated iTunes to version 11 and I can't Find the spot where to upload and sync documents anymore (to use in iAnnotate for instance). I don't have a WiFi connection so iCloud syncing is not an option.

How can I sync documents in iTunes 11?

Answer (score 1):

It's still there but the new views in iTunes can be confusing.

- connect your iPad to your Mac
- in iTunes, select the device in the top row on the right hand side (beside the button for the Store)
- select "Apps" in the top row (about the middle of the screen)
- the same Apps install screen as in iTunes 10 should be displayed, with the document box at the bottom

Comment: This doesn't work, there is no document box at the bottom. I don't have a Mac btw, just a regular laptop.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot please?